# Return JSON objects retrieved from Slack with Django REST

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, slack

I set up a Django REST API with Slack so I could program a support bot. It's working fine in that I can program new messages and responses. However I also want to able to return JSON objects that I've retrieved from Slack.

Here's my views.py

```
class Events(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slack_message = request.data

        #verify token
        if slack_message.get('token') != SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        #checking for url verification
        if slack_message.get('type') == 'url_verification':
            return Response(data=slack_message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        #send a greeting to the bot
        if 'event' in slack_message:
            #process message if event data is contained in it
            event_message = slack_message.get('event')

            #ignore bot's own message
            if event_message.get('subtype') == 'bot_message':
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            #handle the message by parsing the JSON data
            user = event_message.get('user')
            text = event_message.get('text')
            channel = event_message.get('channel')
            bot_text = 'Hi <@{}> :wave:'.format(user)

            #finally use the slack api to post the message with chat.postMessage
            if 'hello' in text.lower():
                Client.api_call(method='chat.postMessage',
                    channel=channel,
                    text=bot_text)
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

So this works fine, I'm using `ngrok` to tunnel to the Slack API. Now I want to return the list of convos in a channel, which I do with `conversations.history`:

```
class ConversationArchive(APIView):
    def save_conversation(self, request):

        conversation_history = Client.api_call(method='conversations.history',
            token='xxx',
            channel='xxx')

        return conversation_history
```

Now when I check the conversation view in my browser it shows me

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "name": "Conversation Archive",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ]
}
```

Which is not the list of conversations, I know my method call on the Slack API is correct because I've tested it in me `Events` view by telling the bot to send the `conversation_history` in the chat, crude but effective. So how would I return this a a JSON object with the framework? Would I need to create and serialize a model?

Comment: Where in `ConversationArchive` are you doing anything with `conversation_history`?  Right now you're just returning a 200 response, which AFAICT is what it's showing when you check the view.  You should actually include `conversation_history` in your return probably?

Comment: @DeniseMauldin Hey thanks for the reply, I changed the code to what I meant to post. I want to return a JSON representation of the convo history. I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Django 1.7+ and if conversation_history is a JSON serializable object, then just provide it as the JsonResponse from the APIView:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class ConversationArchive(APIView):
    def save_conversation(self, request):
        conversation_history = Client.api_call(method='conversations.history',
        token='xxx',
        channel='xxx')

        return JsonResponse(conversation_history)
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is what I'm looking for